# Deserialize property to abstract base reference

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Is it possible to deserialize an aggregate type that has a property to an abstract base type that is a reference, see Aggregate.Base? If not, what is the best workaround?

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Derived))]
public abstract class Base { }

[ProtoContract]
public class Derived : Base
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Aggregate
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    public Base Base { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var value = new Aggregate { Base = new Derived() };
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, value);
            stream.Position = 0;

            // Raises an exception
            // Unable to create type Sage.Estimating.Data.Base: Cannot create an abstract class.
            Serializer.Deserialize<Aggregate>(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Call stack at the point the exception is raised:

> protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source, int key, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.NetObjectOptions options) Line 428 + 0xda bytes    C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.NetObjectSerializer.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 45 + 0x9f bytes  C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.TagDecorator.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 66 + 0x18 bytes C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.PropertyDecorator.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 74 + 0x18 bytes    C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 205 + 0xf bytes   C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(int key, object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 562 + 0xf bytes    C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader reader, System.Type type, object value, bool noAutoCreate) Line 634 + 0x14 bytes  C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) Line 555 + 0x14 bytes  C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type) Line 534 + 0x13 bytes C#
>       protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source) Line 78 + 0x5a bytes  C#

Comment: Will have to look - not at a pc right now, but looks more than a 1-liner

Comment: Hmmm; this is an interesting and non-trivial issue to do with deferred tracking... probably fixable, but ooh, that's a good one ;p I can confirm your test acts as a repro, so will be investigating/fixing this ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for an excellent scenario; not sure how I overlooked that. Basically, it comes down to key tracking, which gets particularly complex during cyclic graphs. In order to get the key registered ASAP, what it *used* to do was (for new objects):

- create an instance of the object
- register it against the known key
- deserialize the payload into the newly created object

Obviously the first step is an error in the case of inheritance, *regardless* of whether the base-type is abstract / non-creatable. What it does now is:

- register a dummy (non-fetchable) value against the known key
- deserialize the payload starting from `null`
- trap the object (update the dummy) as it gets created (this code pretty much already existed, although it was specialised for the "root object" scenario; now made more generic)

The upshot of this is: it now works; your test passes, and the object is of the correct type:

```
var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<Aggregate>(stream);
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Derived), obj.Base.GetType());
```

Needs revision 556 or later.